# How to get store and store view code from Product Review?

Tags: magento-1.7, php, review

I'm using magento 1.7. I want export product reviews from magento. For that, I want to find the store and store view codes of the product review. I tried the below, But It does not work.

```
$review_store = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getStoreId();
$review_storviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getStores();
```

How to get the store and store view from product review object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need load a review before call getStoreId method, like this:

```
$storeId = Mage::getModel('review/review')->load(6)->getStoreId(); //6 is a Review ID.
```

If you have a review object already, you can do this:

```
$storeId = $review->getStoreId();
```

Comment: Nice! How I'm unaware about objects? It works! Thank you Sir.